# Singular integral: NIntegrate fails to converge

Tags: numerical-integration

I need to calculate the following singular integral:

```
NIntegrate[Log[1 + y^2]/Cos[Pi y], {y, 0, 1}]
```

However, it is failing to converge. I have tried to specify `MaxRecursion`, `PrecisionGoal`, and `Exclusions` but neither helped. How does one calculate singular integrals in *Mathematica*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As it stands the integral does not converge! To see that note that

`Series[Log[1 + y^2]/Cos[Pi y], {y, 1/2, 0}]`

returns
$$-\frac{\log \left(\frac{5}{4}\right)}{\pi  \left(y-\frac{1}{2}\right)}-\frac{4}{5 \pi
   }+O\left(y-\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

and a simple pole is not integrable.

What you maybe want to know is Cauchy's principal value of the integral (which is finite). For that, evaluate

`NIntegrate[Log[1 + y^2]/Cos[Pi y], {y, 0, 1/2, 1}, 
 Method -> "PrincipalValue"]`

which returns `-0.281589`.

Comment: Same with `NIntegrate[Log[1 + y^2]/Cos[Pi y], {y, 0, 1}, 
 Method -> "PrincipalValue", Exclusions -> {1/2}]`