# NIntegrate fails to converge

Tags: numerical-integration, precision-and-accuracy

I am trying to compute this integral for different `a` with `0.0001<a<0.5`,

```
 int[a_?NumericQ, r_?NumericQ]:=NIntegrate[Exp[-a/Sqrt[1-x^2]]/(x^2-r^2)^2, {x, 0, r, 1},Method ->"PrincipalValue"]
```

where `0<r<1`. For high `a`, the calculation don't display errors,

```
int[100, 0.8]
(*  1.1619041*10^-44  *)
```

But for `a={0.1,0.01,0.0001}` I get this message error.

```
int[0.1, 0.8]
```

> NIntegrate::inumri: The integrand E^(-(0.1/Sqrt[1-Power[<<2>>]]))/(-0.64+(0.8 -x)^2)^2+E^(-(0.1/Sqrt[1-Power[<<2>>]]))/(-0.64+(0.8 +x)^2)^2 has evaluated to Overflow, Indeterminate, or Infinity for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0.,2.7247563*10^-30}}.

I still can't control the accuracy of the calculation. I proceeded by increasing `WorkingPrecision`, `PrecisionGoal`, `MaxRecursion` but it gives each time different values, I do not even know if it gives the true value.

Please, how to increase the precision of this computation?

Comment: Maybe this could help:
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16254/singular-integral-nintegrate-fails-to-converge

Comment: I already tried with `Method ->"PrincipalValue"` included in my code, thank you @Ofek.

Comment: For `a` near 0, you are effectively trying to evaluate the integral of $1/(x-r)^2$. No wonder it goes south.

Comment: Exectute this code:`Integrate[
 Exp[-a/Sqrt[1 - x^2]]/(x^2 - r^2)^2 /. r -> 1/2 /. a -> 1/10, {x, 0, 
  1}]` then you see the answer ?

Comment: Thank you @Mariusz, but its fails constantly. This is the error: `NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in x near {x} = {0.80076571}. NIntegrate obtained 22482.95271496083 and 13818.221260219178 for the integral and error estimates`.

Comment: Integrate not fail,give you a correct answer.

Comment: No it's not the correct value.

Comment: "not the correct value" - do you have a reference for this integral, and why you expect the answer to be finite?

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the lowest order terms of the Laurant series of the integrand reveals that there are two issues:

```
Series[Exp[-a/Sqrt[1 - x^2]]/(x^2 - r^2)^2, {x, r, -1}] // Simplify
```

> $$\frac{e^{-\frac{a}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}}}{4 r^2
>    (x-r)^2}-\frac{e^{-\frac{a}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}} \left(a
>    r^2+\left(1-r^2\right)^{3/2}\right)}{4 \left(r^3
>    \left(1-r^2\right)^{3/2}\right) (x-r)}+O\left((x-r)^0\right)$$

The first issue is that the $(x-r)^{-2}$ term is not integrable, even not int he principle values sense: It is even so that terms on the left and on the right of the singularity at $x=r$ cannot cancel. The second issue is that term $(x-r)^{-1}$ term *is* integrable in the principal values sense but that the integration domain lies entirely to the left of the singularity $x = r$; so cancellation also cannot happen.

The only reason why `int[100, 0.8]` the terms $e^{-\frac{a}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}}$ are numerically so dominant: At $x = r$, you get numerically $\frac{0}{0}$ and at the first quadrature point to the left of $x =r$ you get numerically $0$ for the integrand. That might be the reason why `NIntegrate` decided to evaluate to `0`. It could also be that `NIntegrate` uses a quadrature rule in this case that does not use interval boundaries as quadrature points (because you warned it that there might be a singularity).

Comment: Thank you @Schumacher, so this integral never converges?

Comment: That's what I tried to explain, yes.

Comment: Serious problem!

Comment: *lol*. Yes. Fortunately, not mine ;)

Comment: Thank you @Schumacher. ;)

Comment: You're welcome. =)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84062/discussion-between-gallagher-and-henrik-schumacher).